# Rest Client with SSL and proxy setting getting connection timeOut

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am using a Rest client with ignore ssl it work fine but it wont work in the future for the production i tried with client certificate. I have both ca certificate and client certifcate i created a client with it but i am getting the error

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
            at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
            at org.app.last.JerseyClient.get_JSON(JerseyClient.java:67)
            at org.app.last.JerseyClient.main(JerseyClient.java:266)
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:564)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
            at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:949)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
            at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
            at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:253)
            at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
            ... 6 more
```

Here is the code of

```
            import com.sun.jersey.api.client.*;
            import javax.net.ssl.*;
            import java.io.*;
            import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
            import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
            import java.net.Proxy;
            import java.net.ProxySelector;
            import java.net.Socket;
            import java.net.URISyntaxException;
            import java.net.URL;
            import java.security.*;
            import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
            import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
            import java.util.List;
            import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
            import com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties;
            import com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HttpURLConnectionFactory;
            import com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler;

            public class JerseyClient {

                private WebResource webResource;
                private Client client;
                //private static final String BASE_URI = "https://localhost:9028/testsecurity2/resources";
                private static final String truststore_path = //my truststore path
                private static final String truststore_password = //my truststore pwd
                private static final String keystore_path = //my truststore path
                private static final String keystore_password = //my truststore pwd
                private static final String url = //my host url

                public JerseyClient() {
                    com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig config = new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig(); 
                    // SSL configuration
                    config.getProperties().put(com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, new com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties(getHostnameVerifier(), getSSLContext()));
                    //client = Client.create(config);
                    Client client = new Client(new URLConnectionClientHandler(
                            new HttpURLConnectionFactory() {
                        Proxy p = null;
                        @Override
                        public HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(URL url)
                                throws IOException {
                            if (p == null) {
                                if (System.getProperties().containsKey("http.proxyHost")) {
                                    p = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
                                            new InetSocketAddress(
                                            System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"),
                                            Integer.getInteger("http.proxyPort", 8080)));
                                } else {
                                    p = Proxy.NO_PROXY;
                                }
                            }
                            return (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(p);
                        }
                    }), config);
                    webResource = client.resource(url);
                }

                public <T> T get_XML(Class<T> responseType) throws UniformInterfaceException {
                    return webResource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(responseType);
                }

                public <T> T get_JSON(Class<T> responseType,String input) throws UniformInterfaceException {
                    return webResource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(responseType,input);
                }

                public void close() {
                    client.destroy();
                }

                public void setUsernamePassword(String username, String password) {
                    client.addFilter(new com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, password));
                }

                private HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
                    return new HostnameVerifier() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean verify(String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    };
                }

                private SSLContext getSSLContext() {

                    TrustManager mytm[] = null;
                    KeyManager mykm[] = null;

                    try {
                        mytm = new TrustManager[]{new MyX509TrustManager(truststore_path, truststore_password.toCharArray())};
                        mykm = new KeyManager[]{new MyX509KeyManager(keystore_path, keystore_password.toCharArray())};
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    SSLContext ctx = null;
                    try {
                        ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                        ctx.init(mykm, mytm, null);
                    } catch (java.security.GeneralSecurityException ex) {
                    }
                    return ctx;
                }

                /**
                 * Taken from http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html
                 *
                 */
                static class MyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

                    /*
                     * The default PKIX X509TrustManager9.  We'll delegate
                     * decisions to it, and fall back to the logic in this class if the
                     * default X509TrustManager doesn't trust it.
                     */
                    X509TrustManager pkixTrustManager;

                    MyX509TrustManager(String trustStore, char[] password) throws Exception {
                        this(new File(trustStore), password);
                    }

                    MyX509TrustManager(File trustStore, char[] password) throws Exception {
                        // create a "default" JSSE X509TrustManager.

                        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

                        ks.load(new FileInputStream(trustStore), password);

                        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
                        tmf.init(ks);

                        TrustManager tms[] = tmf.getTrustManagers();

                        /*
                         * Iterate over the returned trustmanagers, look
                         * for an instance of X509TrustManager.  If found,
                         * use that as our "default" trust manager.
                         */
                        for (int i = 0; i < tms.length; i++) {
                            if (tms[i] instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                                pkixTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tms[i];
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        /*
                         * Find some other way to initialize, or else we have to fail the
                         * constructor.
                         */
                        throw new Exception("Couldn't initialize");
                    }

                    /*
                     * Delegate to the default trust manager.
                     */
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                            throws CertificateException {
                        try {
                            pkixTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
                        } catch (CertificateException excep) {
                            // do any special handling here, or rethrow exception.
                        }
                    }

                    /*
                     * Delegate to the default trust manager.
                     */
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                            throws CertificateException {
                        try {
                            pkixTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
                        } catch (CertificateException excep) {
                            /*
                             * Possibly pop up a dialog box asking whether to trust the
                             * cert chain.
                             */
                        }
                    }

                    /*
                     * Merely pass this through.
                     */
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return pkixTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Inspired from http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html
                 *
                 */
                static class MyX509KeyManager implements X509KeyManager {

                    /*
                     * The default PKIX X509KeyManager.  We'll delegate
                     * decisions to it, and fall back to the logic in this class if the
                     * default X509KeyManager doesn't trust it.
                     */
                    X509KeyManager pkixKeyManager;

                    MyX509KeyManager(String keyStore, char[] password) throws Exception {
                        this(new File(keyStore), password);
                    }

                    MyX509KeyManager(File keyStore, char[] password) throws Exception {
                        // create a "default" JSSE X509KeyManager.

                        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                        ks.load(new FileInputStream(keyStore), password);

                        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509", "SunJSSE");
                        kmf.init(ks, password);

                        KeyManager kms[] = kmf.getKeyManagers();

                        /*
                         * Iterate over the returned keymanagers, look
                         * for an instance of X509KeyManager.  If found,
                         * use that as our "default" key manager.
                         */
                        for (int i = 0; i < kms.length; i++) {
                            if (kms[i] instanceof X509KeyManager) {
                                pkixKeyManager = (X509KeyManager) kms[i];
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        /*
                         * Find some other way to initialize, or else we have to fail the
                         * constructor.
                         */
                        throw new Exception("Couldn't initialize");
                    }

                    public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String arg0) {
                        return pkixKeyManager.getPrivateKey(arg0);
                    }

                    public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String arg0) {
                        return pkixKeyManager.getCertificateChain(arg0);
                    }

                    public String[] getClientAliases(String arg0, Principal[] arg1) {
                        return pkixKeyManager.getClientAliases(arg0, arg1);
                    }

                    public String chooseClientAlias(String[] arg0, Principal[] arg1, Socket arg2) {
                        return pkixKeyManager.chooseClientAlias(arg0, arg1, arg2);
                    }

                    public String[] getServerAliases(String arg0, Principal[] arg1) {
                        return pkixKeyManager.getServerAliases(arg0, arg1);
                    }

                    public String chooseServerAlias(String arg0, Principal[] arg1, Socket arg2) {
                        return pkixKeyManager.chooseServerAlias(arg0, arg1, arg2);
                    }
                }
                public static void main(String[] args) {

                    JerseyClient client = new JerseyClient();       
                     Object response = client.get_JSON(String.class,"");
                     System.out.println(response);
                     // do whatever with response
                     client.close();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

check the below url which may useful to you http://snippet-pocket.blogspot.in/2010/07/ssl-authentication-with-apache.html which explain the client authentication.

Comment: Please understand that stackoverflow requires self contained answers that explains the problem. Link only answers are discouraged